# Suggestion on extracting <scripts> tags of java scripts with Java program

Tags: java, javascript, parsing

I am trying to write a program which access web pages using Apache HttpClient APIs and fetches the web page. Now I want to extract the javascripts in the fetched pages .. I am wondering is there any Api or some thing? No sure is DOMparser does that? Any suggestion

Thanks for you help and guidance.

With regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html), especially the example about [Finding Specific Tags](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/samples/console/src/FindSpecificTags.java).